# SQL Update - variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, sql-update

I've been stuck with a problem with SQL , about updating table (couldn't find answer anywhere).

The problem looks like:

```
Update TABLE1
    SET @variable1 = @variable2
    WHERE SomeColumn = @variable3;
```

Where variable1 and variable3 is type of varchar(50) , and variable2 is type of int. How can I make this working? I've been trying with EXEC or many other simple options, but they seem not working for me.

In the code example I've given here, value from variable2 is assigned to variable1 instead of a column with name equals to variable1, and when I try with Exec, It can't read variable2 (because of int type) properly.

Comment: The query does not make sense. What is it doing?

Comment: I was supposed to write a procedure which makes Table looks differently (The same as I would use PIVOT , but i couldn't use that operation), and that's why At the end i need to Update Table with 3 variables. The answers under this post are working...but there seems to be another problem in my procedure..."Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 85
Invalid column name 'Doors'." Don't know why SQL instead of seeing this as a value of row , in column called SomeColumn , It is looking for a column with name "Doors"...
Ps.I do have a record Doors under SomeColumn column :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @variable1 varchar(50)
DECLARE @variable2 varchar(50)
DECLARE @variable3 varchar(50)
DECLARE @Sql varchar(max)

SET @variable1 = col1

Set @sql = 'Update TABLE1 SET' + @variable1 +' ='+ @variable2 +
    'WHERE SomeColumn = '+ @variable3

EXEC (@Sql)
```

If you need to dynamically set @variable1

Comment: Right, and for int or numeric number you should use "cast" function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = '
Update TABLE1
    SET @variable1 = @variable2
    WHERE SomeColumn = @variable3';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '@variable1', @variable1);

exec sp_executesql @sql,
                   N'@variable2 int, @variable3 varchar(50)',
                   @variable2 = @variable2, @variable3 = @variable3;
```

Note:  The `replace()` is used because identifiers (table names, column names, function calls, and so on) cannot be represented by parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This query doesn't do what you think it does! You're getting the "Doors" error when you supply the value "Doors" in the parameter @Variable1. @Variable1 has to be a valid column name in TABLE1. SomeColumn has nothing to do with it.

Whenever schema elements (column names, table names) are to be decided at runtime, you need to dynamically construct your sql with string methods, as the other answers say. This, I would say, is *always a bad idea*. You *never* have to do this. You've kinda added to the confusion by not having meaningful names for your variables. You've likely done this because at design time, you don't know anything about your variables apart from that they're variable. This for me is a clear sign that you're trying to do too much with one query. No one coming after you will be able to maintain this code. You will likely forget what on earth you were trying to do when you wrote it. (And it's still not clear to me that you could get where you want to go if you persevere).

Comment: Well , this naming schema was just made for stack's overflow question. In my real query I have normal names of colums , I just didn't wanted to put here some strange words in different language because it was supposed to be example as simple to understand as it could ;d 
By the way , I've found answer for my problem. Each time i've put variable , I had to put in EXEC something like this:"...'''+@variable+'''..." and it worked for me ;) 
Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TAB') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TAB
END

CREATE TABLE #TAB
(CH1 INT,CH2 INT,CH3 INT)

DECLARE @CH2 INT = NULL , @CH3 INT=NULL,@SPID INT=NULL,@SQL NVARCHAR(4000)='', @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(50)= ''

SET @ParmDefinition='@SPID INT,@CH2 INT OUTPUT,@CH3 INT OUTPUT'

SET @SQL='UPDATE TOP(1) #TAB SET CH1=@SPID,@CH2= CH2,@CH3= CH3 WHERE CH1 IS NULL'

INSERT INTO #TAB
(CH2 ,CH3 )
SELECT 1,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,3 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,4

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #TAB WHERE CH1 IS NULL)
BEGIN
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, @ParmDefinition,@SPID =@@SPID,  @CH2=@CH2 OUTPUT,@CH3=@CH3 OUTPUT;  

    SELECT * FROM #TAB
    SELECT @CH2,@CH3

END
```